# Prove programs without installing ubuntu? only running with the cd?

Tags: software-installation, programming, cd

I have a question, I would like to test a program in ubuntu to see if that works better in Windows 7 ("Android SDK"). 
But I do not want to install ubuntu on the pc, and do not want to use a virtual machine. 
Could only install programs to try booting from the cd or impossible to install programs from the cd. 
Sorry if my English is bad.

Comment: With all of those do not wants, installing the Android SDK, getting an AVD, pulling in the current API, setting up toolchain paths, etc is just too time consuming to do live and lose it all when you reboot...

Comment: is true, I just want to test if I do better than in windows. 
If it works better be installing ubuntu on my pc, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am answering as far as I understand your Question like " Is it possible to install programs/Applications in Ubuntu in live mode ?"

If it is your question then We say YES. You can install programs at live mode also.

Simply , start the live mode. Open Terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After this either from Terminal or from Software center you can go for installing your Application.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I mean you start from the cd, and there is a choice in Spanish called "probar ubuntu sin instalar"    I guess in English will put "try ubuntu without installing"

Comment: @user293998 Yes you have ti choose that. :) It will start live mode.